# Set UITableViewCell contents only once?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, timer, cells

I am using the `MZTimerLabel` library to display a countdown timer on each of my cells in a `UITableView`. I set the cell contents and countdown time of each cell in the function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. However, if I do this, I realized that if I scroll through my `UITableView`, the cells that the view cannot display have their countdown timer set again once I scroll back up to see the cells that weren't previously displayed. This is bad because the timer value is constantly changing between what was previously displayed before it went out of the view and what is currently displayed when it is back in the view. Is there a way to set the countdown timer for each `UITableViewCell` only once? I've looked at this link for help: [UITableView :cellForRowAtIndexPath Continues being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186992/uitableview-cellforrowatindexpath-continues-being-called) but I'm not sure if there's any other way. Here is my code if that helps. Any help would be appreciated!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return offerCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}


func offerCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> OfferCell{
    //Dequeue a "reusable" cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(offerCellIdentifier) as! OfferCell
    setCellContents(cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func setCellContents(cell:OfferCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
    let item = self.offers[indexPath.row]
    var expirDate: NSTimeInterval = item.dateExpired()!.doubleValue

    //Get current time and subtract it by the predicted expiration date of the cell. Subtract them to get the countdown timer.
    var currentDate = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    var timer = MZTimerLabel(label: cell.timeLeft, andTimerType: MZTimerLabelTypeTimer)
    timer.delegate = self
    var countdownTime = expirDate - currentDate
    timer.setCountDownTime(countdownTime)
    timer.start()
}
```

Comment: dispatch_once might help you....

Comment: @AgentChocks. I just tried the `dispatch_once` method but that didn't seem to change anything. I wrapped getting the current time and such in a dispatch_once function call and I include a print statement in there and the print statement is constantly called when I scroll up and down my UITableView.

Comment: means you want the same single cell even if you scrolled up and down is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I just want the same timer even if i scroll up or down.